# How to fix: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'event.relatedTarget.parentNode')

Tags: javascript

This came up as an error after I uploaded a website I'm currently working on.

TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'event.relatedTarget.parentNode')

Any ideas on how to fix this/ what I should replace it with?

Comment: Without any code, how is anybody supposed to help you? Maybe `if (event && event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.parentNode)`

Comment: Please provide more code (and context) so we're more able to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: The code is in the subject line

Comment: @user3237758 What you have in the subject line is the error not code... Moreover, The code (and error) should be in the body not subject line... Please edit your question, fix your subject line, and add code so we can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without any other context, if `event.relatedTarget.parentNode` is giving you this error then it means that either `event`, or `event.relatedTarget` is null.

So:

```
if (event && event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.parentNode) {
    // your code here
}
```

Now how you should handle the case where `event` or `event.relatedTarget` is null? I have no idea because you haven't given enough information for anybody to have any idea what you are doing.

What you probably need to do is figure out why it's sometimes (or maybe all the time) null.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I was trying to create the number guess game at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash. 
Although I typed the codes exactly, I kept getting the TypeError: null is not an object message for at least two of my codes.  When I thought they were cleared I would get another TypeError: Number is not a function, and trailing zeros were added to my guess answers. I would even get an error on the Field Input focus guessField.focus().  But after intensive researching, not only did I read that it seems to be a common error with Safari browsers, but I finally figured it out.

All of the error messages that I was receiving was within the function checkGuess(). Even though I defined the variables before the function, they weren't all being defined or recognized. The biggest problem was surrounding the input field. The crazy thing is that it was working perfectly when I first created it and somewhere after a few clicks it just wasn't.

What I did was redefine my variable for the random number, removed it from global and into the lexical environment. It became better defined directly associated with the function.  The game was functioning again.
This was the original code:

```
<body>

    <div class="game">
        <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>

        <p>
            We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or fewer. We'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.
        </p>

        <label for="guessField">
            Enter a guess: </label>
        <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField" tabindex="1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Guess" class="guessSubmit" tabeindex="2" onclick="checkGuess()">

        <span class="resultParas">
            <p class="guesses"></p>
            <p class="lastResult"></p>
            <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
        </span> 

    </div>

</body>

<script>
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

var guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
var lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');

var guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
var guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');

var guessCount = 1;
var resetButton;
guessField.focus();


function checkGuess() {
  var userGuess = randomNumber(guessField.value);
  if (guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';

  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if (guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = '!!!GAME OVER!!!';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
    } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
    }
  }

  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();

  guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);
}

function setGameOver() {
  guessField.disabled = true;
  guessSubmit.disabled = true;
  resetButton = document.createElement('button');
  resetButton.textContent = 'Start new game';
  document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
}

function resetGame() {
  guessCount = 1;

  var resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
  for (var i = 0 ; i < resetParas.length ; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
  }

  resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);

  guessField.disabled = false;
  guessSubmit.disabled = false;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();

  lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
</script>
```

This is what I changed the checkGuest function to:

```
var guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
var lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');

var guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
var guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');

var guessCount = 1;
var resetButton;
guessField.focus();


function checkGuess() {
    var userGuess = guessField.value;
    guessField.value = Number;
    Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if(guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
    }
    guesses.textContent += userGuess + '';

    if(userGuess === Number) {
        lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
        lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        lowOrHi.textContent = '';
        setGameOver();
    } else if(guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = '!!!Game Over!!!';
    setGameOver();  
    } else {
        lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
        lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        if(userGuess < Number) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
        } else if(userGuess > Number) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
        }
    }

    guessCount++;
    guessField.value = '';
    guessField.focus();

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);
}
```